# How to use 'PlatformView' in Agora as an input video Stream using Agora RawData in Flutter

Tags: flutter, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation, platformview

A platform view has been registered and is working when i use
`AndroidVIew(viewType: 'OpenGLDisplayView')`
But it doesn't work when i initiate an observer like this:

```
var handle = await engine.getNativeHandle();
await AgoraRtcRawdata.registerVideoFrameObserver(handle);
```

Here is configuration of PlatformView in .kt file:

```
mGLDisplayViewFactory = GLDisplayViewFactory(messenger)
        binding.platformViewRegistry
            .registerViewFactory("OpenGLDisplayView", mGLDisplayViewFactory)
```

NOTE: I am performing this configuration in a local package which i am accessing via path. Do i need to change my mainActivity.java ?

How to Actively use 'OpenGLDisplayView' as a custom video stream?

Packages are:

```
agora_rtc_rawdata: ^0.1.0
  agora_rtc_engine: ^6.1.1`
```

when i use it in AgoraView the App Crashes`

```
 _initEngine() async {
   

    engine =   createAgoraRtcEngine();
    
    await engine.initialize(RtcEngineContext(
        appId: config.appId,
        channelProfile: ChannelProfileType.channelProfileLiveBroadcasting));

    engine.registerEventHandler(RtcEngineEventHandler(
        onJoinChannelSuccess: (RtcConnection connection, int elapsed) {
      log('onJoinChannelSuccess connection: ${connection.toJson()} elapsed: $elapsed');
      setState(() {
        isJoined = true;
      });
    }, onUserJoined: (RtcConnection connection, int rUid, int elapsed) {
      log('onUserJoined connection: ${connection.toJson()} remoteUid: $rUid elapsed: $elapsed');
      setState(() {
        remoteUid.add(rUid);
      });
    }, onUserOffline:
            (RtcConnection connection, int rUid, UserOfflineReasonType reason) {
      log('onUserOffline connection: ${connection.toJson()} remoteUid: $rUid reason: $reason');
      setState(() {
        remoteUid.remove(rUid);
      });
    }));
    
    await engine.enableVideo();
    await engine.startPreview();
    setState(() {
      startPreview = true;
    });
 

    await engine.joinChannel(
        token: config.token,
        channelId: config.channelId,
        uid: 0,
        options: ChannelMediaOptions());
          var handle = await engine.getNativeHandle();
  //  await AgoraRtcRawdata.registerAudioFrameObserver(handle);

  await AgoraRtcRawdata.registerVideoFrameObserver(handle);}
```

AgoraVideoView Code:

```
  AgoraVideoView(
                controller: VideoViewController(
                  rtcEngine: engine,
                  canvas: VideoCanvas(uid: 0),
                ),
              ),
```

Note the PlatformView works fine when i use it in AndroidView:

```
 AndroidView(
        viewType: 'OpenGLDisplayView'
                       ),
```